# Prove that the function $f(z) = \sqrt{|Re(z) Im(z)|}$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm asked the following question:

> Prove that the function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
>
> $$f(z) = \sqrt{|Re(z) Im(z)|}$$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation,
>   but not differentiable there.

However, the function is basically $f(x+iy) = \sqrt{|xy|},$ i.e $f(z) = u + iv$, $u = \sqrt{|xy|}$ and $v = 0$.

However, for example, the partial derivatives of $f$ wrt $x$ is $\frac{\pm \sqrt{y} }{ 2|x|} $, and this function does not have a limit at the origin, so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x } $ does not exist at the origin, hence how can it satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation ?

However

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equation**s** : there are 2 of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you calculate partial derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ you have to set $y=0$. So the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is $\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{0-0} x$ which is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $ \frac{u(x,0)-u(0,0)}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. This shows that $u_x(0,0)$ exists and $=0$. Similar $u_y(0,0)=0$.